# Concatenate a character to a variable's value in Bash

Tags: bash

first of all, I want you guys to know I did my research and found a ton of documentation about the subject of course, but none of them works.

I have a text file with each line being:

newUserToAdd,inThisGroup

i.e:

John,Client

So trying to create the user's list if they are not already there, and to place them inThisGroup. The thing is if the group name is the text file is Client, I want the group name in the computer to be "Clients". So I need to add the "s" character. I tried many ways, but none of them works.

Here's a bit of my script if that can help to understand.

```
  for line in `cat /home/jonathan/Desktop/Utilisateurs.txt`
  do
   echo $line > /dev/null
   user=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
   group=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
   groups=${group}"s"

  if [ `grep $group /etc/group` ] ; then 
   echo "Ce groupe existe. Aucune action à faire."
  else
   #echo "Ce groupe n'existe pas. Création immédiate."
   echo $groups
   #groupadd $groups
  fi
  done
```

But it keeps giving me this kind of output... (There's 3 group names in my list, in French: "Superviseur","Technicien" and "Client". The console output is:

```
    superviseur
    sechnicien
    sechnicien
    slient
    slient
    slient
    superviseur
```

Why does it keep changing the first letter instead of adding the letter at the end ?

Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: `groups="${group}s"` should work, but so should `groups=${group}"s"`. You could smack it with a hammer and try `groups=$(echo "${groups}s")` That seems a little silly though

Comment: Thanks for your comment JNevill. Unfortunately it didn't work either :(

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describing best practices for iterating through a file line-by-line.

Comment: This is a school project, and the meaning ot the project is to use basic if, loops ans such. What would you suggest instead ?

Comment: ...there are a whole lot of other miscellaneous bugs and mispractices here -- see http://shellcheck.net/ for several.

Comment: Re: what I would suggest instead -- follow the link.

Comment: Also, see the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Literally the **very first thing** in the section "Before asking about problematic code" tells you to check for and deal with DOS newlines.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this. I should've look harder. Thanks a lot for your help, I'm reading this right away.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably being caused by carriage returns at the end of each line in your `Utilisateurs.txt` file. Use the `dos2unix` utility to convert `\r\n` (Windows-style newlines) to `\n` (Unix-style newlines).

This utility may be found in a repository, depending on your distribution (e.g., in the [Canonical repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/dos2unix)), or it may be created manually (e.g., as a quick [sed script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540180&p=9644287#post9644287)).

The reason that you are seeing this issue is that carriage returns (`\r`) pull the cursor to the left of the line without moving the cursor *down* one line. This can be useful in some cases, such as when you desire to rewrite the current line. However, this is probably not what you are looking for here.

For more context, Bash uses its internal field separator (IFS) to determine delimiters when processing strings in commands such as `for`. The default IFS in Bash is `$' \n\t'`, which includes spaces, newlines, and tabs but not carriage returns. This means that your `for`-loop will separate on newlines but will keep the carriage returns intact.

Comment: Yep that was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot for your input !